# Leet: 347. Top K Frequent Elements

Tags: python, string

I have tried to solve the leetcode problem using list and dictionary. it passes for a few test cases but fails for some due to the range(k) passes as a parameter. Is there a way I could take care of all edge cases
leetcode link:https://leetcode.com/problems/top-k-frequent-elements/

My soln:

```
class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        d={}
        for each in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[each] not in d:
                d[nums[each]]=0
            d[nums[each]]+=1
        res=[]
        if len(d)==k:
            return nums
        l=sorted(d.values(),reverse=True)
        for i in range(k):
            for k,v in d.items():
                if l[i]==v:
                    res.append(k)
        return res
```

Answer (score 1):

Others have given some solutions. I'd like to point out some of the problems in your code:

1. when `len(d) == k`, we need to return `d.keys()` instead of `nums`.

For example, when the `nums = [1,1,1,1]` and `k = 1`, we just need to return `[1]` instead of `[1,1,1,1]`.

2. Try not to use variables with the same name.

We have a variable `k` in the input, and when iterating `dict.items()`, we don't want to create another variable named as `k`.

3. Think about a test case:

```
nums = [1,2,2,3,3]
k = 2
```

Your code will return `[2,3,2,3]` instead of `[2,3]`. Because `l=[2,2,1]` and elements appearing twice (`2,3`) will be added twice. One possible way to solve is adding `d[k] = -1` after `res.append(k)`.

```py
class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        d={}
        for each in range(len(nums)):
            if nums[each] not in d:
                d[nums[each]]=0
            d[nums[each]]+=1
        res=[]
        if len(d)==k:
            return d.keys()
        l=sorted(d.values(),reverse=True)
        for i in range(k):
            for k,v in d.items():
                if l[i]==v:
                    res.append(k)
                    d[k] = -1
        return res
```

Comment: Thank-you soo much for pointing out the flaws in my code, it help me better understand where have I gone wrong. The 3rd point was exactly what I was looking for :)

Comment: So the time complexity will be O( m*n)?

Comment: You're welcome! Assume that the size of `nums` is `n`. The first for loop takes O(n). The size of `d.keys()` is at most `n`, while the size of `d.values()` is at most `sqrt(n)` (when all the elements have different frequencies). Thus the sorting takes O(sqrt(n) * log(sqrt(n))). And the final for loop takes O(k * n). The overall time complexity is O(k * n).

Answer (score 0):

the easiest solution to this would be to just count all items in the list and then, sort by count, like this

```py
def topKfrequent(nums, k):
    d = dict()
    for n in nums:
        d[n] = d.setdefault(n, 0) + 1
    sortedNumsKeys = sorted(d.keys(), key=lambda x: d[x], reverse=True)
    return sortedNumsKeys[:k]
```

Comment: `sortedNumsKeys = sorted(d, key=d.__getitem__, reverse=True)` would be a bit more concise

Answer (score 0):

Another solution using [`collections.Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter.most_common):

```py
from collections import Counter

class Solution:
    def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
        return [i for i, _ in Counter(nums).most_common(k)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Soln:

```
class Solution:
def topKFrequent(self, nums: List[int], k: int) -> List[int]:
    d={}
    for each in range(len(nums)):
        if nums[each] not in d:
            d[nums[each]]=0
        d[nums[each]]+=1
    res=[]
    if len(d)==k:
        return d.keys()
    l=sorted(d.values(),reverse=True)
    for i in range(k):
        for key,v in d.items():
            if l[i]==v:
                res.append(key)
                d[key] = -1
    return res
```